# Intercepting HTTP request on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I need to intercept all HTTP requests on a Mac OS X client and record the request url in it. I know on Windows machine, I can implement a Winsock LSP and have it intercept all winsock calls. Is there a equivalent on Mac OS X? Thanks.

If you don't have the direct answer, I'll appreciate if you can point me to where these Max system programming questions are usually asked/answered.

Comment: Do you need this as part of your application or just to debug something?

Comment: This isn't actually a programming question - it's a system administration and monitoring question, and I bet there are tools to do exactly what this guy needs.  Please bump to serverfault or superuser.

Comment: This is a programming question. First I need to find out ways to implement it, and then I'll program it. As I said, I've already find out how to program this for Windows, now I need to do the same for Mac OS X.

Comment: I suggest you look at dtrace or adding a proxy into the network settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [divert sockets](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2008/06/using-divert-sockets-to-log-http.html) but you need root access.

Comment: Thanks. Forgive my ignorance on Mac programming, but if I understand correctly, that python script looks like a one-time thing. You have to run that script every time your OS reboots. What I need is something like a Windows service, which runs automatically every time your OS boots.

Comment: @Tong If you want something that runs every time your OS boots, look into launchd http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html . If this is something that only needs to be run as part of your application, then you can just re-implement that in your application, and make sure your application is run as root.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks for your info, it's really helpful to me. As for implementing the above suggested divert sockets, what language/sdk/ide should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to monitor the http requests of your application, I suggest dtrace, or possibly just printf.

Comment: Actually, I need to monitor all http requests made by all the browsers.